# Change HTML tag content with PHP variable

Tags: php, html

What is wrong with this:

```
<?php echo '<div id="testID"> <p class="testClass">
<?php echo $textToPrint; ?> </p> </div>'; ?>
```

I tried the innerHTML assignment, but it prints some mess (puts some additional characters, not just the ones in $textToPrint, which is a string php variable).

This one works perfectly fine:

```
<?php echo '<h3>helloe</h3><br><p class="testClass">messing around</p>
<br>'; ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you forget to post the code?

Comment: you either never close the first PHP tag, or you never removed the second opening tag(s). http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: <script style="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("wordID").innerHTML = '<?php echo $textToPrint; ?>';
 </script>
This does not give me good text from the string PHP variable. It's mixed up with other non-letter chars.

Comment: you're script above won't work because javascript is browser based and php is server based, why cant you just put `<div id="wordID"><?php echo $textToPrint; ?> </div>` direct on the page ? if you can't then use AJAX to update the div in question....

Answer (score 1):

you don't need two echo just on is ok try

```
  <?php echo '<div id="testID"> <p class="testClass">' . $textToPrint .'</p> </div>'; ?>
```

Comment: what i have edited your answer, how? and sry?

Comment: @ob_start not probem i have reject the editing can happen..

Comment: ok, didnt now and klickt wrong two :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<div id="testID"> <p class="testClass">'; ?> #<--missing
<?php echo $textToPrint; ?> </p> </div> <!--remove-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close the php tags and quotes:

```
<?php echo '<div id="testID"> <p class="testClass">'; ?>
<?php echo $textToPrint . '</p> </div>'; ?>
```

Or in one sentence in complete PHP:

```
<?php echo '<div id="testID"><p class="testClass">'.$textToPrint.'</p></div>'; ?>
```

Or in html with only the php variable in PHP

```
<div id="testID"><p class="testClass"><?php echo $textToPrint;?></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
<?php 
    echo "<div id='testID'> <p class='testClass'> $textToPrint </p> </div>"; 
?>
```

Good Luck!